# Display custom form in Django admin

Tags: django

I created a custom user model with `country` in it:

**models.py**

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="None")
```

Then added custom forms with form field `country` which is a `ChoiceField` and shows all the countries:

**forms.py**

```py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=sorted(COUNTRIES.items()), label="Country")

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=sorted(COUNTRIES.items()), label="Country")
    class Meta(UserChangeForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then I registered it in the admin with:

**admin.py**

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'is_staff',]


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

It registered and everything is working fine, I am able to save the model with Django shell and programmatically, but I am not able to display it in the admin console. When I try to try to create a new user from the admin, I just see three fields - username, password and password confirmation.

Do I have to extend the admin template for this new field to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will have to `add_fieldsets` under `CustomUserAdmin` in `admin.py`:

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'is_staff',]

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'country'),
        }),
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: `add_form` doesn't exist in 4.1+. Overriding `get_form` should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4.1+, the `add_form` option on a `ModelAdmin` has been removed. You should instead use the `get_form()` argument, like follows:

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        if not change and not obj:
            self.form = self.add_form
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```